# Resetting an Application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I've four activities in my app. I pressed home button when I was in third activity. Then I restarted my application. Instead of showing the first activity, it shows third activity. Please help me to reset the app when I press home button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to kill your application when you hit home so that it restarts every time you can place a call to `finish()` in your `onStop` and `onPause` methods. The default behavior for the home button is to simply stop the activity instead of exiting it, so navigating to your application again is just resuming from where you left off, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPause` / `onStop` save your current activity number into SharedPreferences or into a Bundle. Read it in `onResume` and ccordingly open the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your activities in Recenttask you should use `excludeFromRecent = "true"` tags in your activities declaration in manifest file, like below

```
        <activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
         />
```